# Ignoring NUnit test from the console using a wildcard

Tags: nunit, nunit-console, nunit-2.5.9

Are there a way that one can ignore unit tests when running NUnit from the command line based on a wildcard?

Say for example I don't want to run any tests that end with IntegrationTest? In that case I would like to say ignore all tests containing `*IntegrationTest*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, NUnit does not support the use of wildcards for specifying which tests should or not be executed. As you're using NUnit 2.5.9, you have a few other options for doing something similar:

- Tag your integration tests fixtures with a specific **category**, such as:

```
[Category("Integration")]
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTests {  }
```

and use the following command to run your tests:

> nunit-console myassembly.dll /exclude:Integration

- Separate your integration tests in **different assemblies** and use the
  command below:

> nunit-console nunit.tests.integration.dll

If you upgrade your version to NUnit 2.6.2, you can also use a separate list of tests in a text file, and run them using

> nunit-console /runlist:testlist.txt nunit.tests.dll

Comment: That is what I expected as I couldn't find anything along these lines. Thanks for clarifying that.